# No sound is playing when running program

Tags: c, background-music

I am trying to figure out how to play sounds when making a program in c. I have been searching all over the internet and I learned i can use Play sound. I followed the instructions I saw by adding certain libraries to my code and adding a linker.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>

int main(void) 
{
    PlaySound("C:\\Users\\chris\\Downloads\\pokemon-red-and-blue-music-opening-theme.wav", NULL,     SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using devc++ as my IDE to run my c program. The linker i used was -lwinmm. Whenever i compile and run my code, the program compiles and runs but it does not play any music for some reason. I made sure to copy the paths of my wav file but it is still not working. I would like to know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: `SND_ASYNC` is telling it to run in the background, but you're immediately exiting, so you aren't giving it any _time_ in which to play in the background. Either don't exit immediately, or take out the ASYNC flag.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I noticed after trying to implement the playsound in one of my programs that whenever it encounters the play sound function, instead of playing the background music I want , a single beep sound can be heard instead

Comment: That sounds like a question worth asking about, but it's different from the question you're asking now.